# Can I safely disable IEEE 802.1X from a Windows XP laptop connecting to a wireless network

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

Sony VAIO running Windows XP sp3 is routinely dropping its wifi connection.  The wireless router itself is fine insofar as it powers several other wireless devices without incidents of drops.

I've referred to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/372153/troubleshooting-sony-vaio-intermittent-wifi-connection) which suggests disabling AEGIS Protocol (IEEE 802.1s) v 3.5.3.0 from my Sony's connection properties.  I've read a bunch of posts on how to do it, but I'm having a hard time determining whether I ought to be connecting wireless without it.

Is it safe to disable on a home wifi network (WPA2-PSK network authentication)